# Mongodb find() return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

When ever I try to just use a simple find() for my mongodb it returns undefined.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

    db.collection('pokemon').find({ $search: { $text: 'Pikachu' } }).toArray(function(err, data){ console.log(data) })

});
```

EDIT:

Turns out I never created an index by putting

```
db.collection('pokemon').createIndex({Name: 'text'})
```

before all the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, every time where you have:

```
function(err, data){ console.log(data) }
```

you should check errors:

```
function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Data:', data);
  }
}
```

Then you will probably see what's going on.

This is also true for the database connection itself - instead of:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  // use db here
});
```

you should handle errors:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    // handle errors
  } else {
    // use db here
  }
});
```

If you don't handle errors then don't be surprised that you don't know why you don't get values.

Comment: Turns out I just forgot to creatIndex